# Grabbing the value of a HTML form input field?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib

There's a web page similar to: www.example.com/form.php

I want to use Python to grab one of the values from the HTML form on the page.  For example, if the form had  I could get the value "test" returned

I have googled this extensively but most relate to posting form data, or have advice to use Django or cgi-bin.  I don't have access to the server directly so I can't do that.

I thought the library REQUESTS could do it but I can't see it in the documentation.

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="" action="formpost.php" name="form1" id="form1">
<input type="text" name"field1" value="this is field1">
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="secret key field">
</form>
</body>
```

As an example, I'd like something like this in Python:

```
import special_library

html = special_library.get("http://www.example.com/form.php")
print html.get_field("wanted")
```

Has anyone got any suggestions to achieve this?  Or any libraries I may not have thought of or been aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `requests` library, and `lxml`

Try this:

```py
import requests
from lxml import html

s = requests.Session()
resp = s.get("http://www.example.com/form.php")
doc = html.fromstring(resp.text)

wanted_value = doc.xpath("//input[@class='wanted_class_name']/@value")
print(wanted_value)
```

You can check following resources:

- [`requests`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/)
- [`xpath`](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)

Comment: I did it!

This worked:

```
import requests
import lxml.html

s = requests.session()
resp = s.get("http://example.com/myform.php")

doc = lxml.html.fromstring(resp.text)
form = doc.forms[0]
print(form.fields["wanted_text_field"])
```

Thanks for your suggestion, lxml worked very well!